# "Error running WSGI application" while hosting a Tornado-based Python application on PythonAnywhere

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, tornado, web-hosting, pythonanywhere

I am trying to host the [Virus on Network](https://github.com/projectmesa/mesa/tree/master/examples/virus_on_network) from Python and [Mesa](https://github.com/projectmesa/mesa) library. [Mesa is using Tornado](https://github.com/projectmesa/mesa/blob/master/mesa/visualization/ModularVisualization.py) to visualize graphics on a server. [According to PythonAnywhere](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/UsingTornado/), it seems Tornado is not preferred since it has asynchronous capacity, but it should still work when asynchronous features are not used. I am a beginner at web hosting, I tried the followings but didn't work.

run.py

```
virus_on_network.server import server

app_server = server

if __name__=='__main__':
    app_server.launch()
```

wsgi.py

```
import sys
path = '/home/ABC123/mysite/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

import tornado.web
import tornado.wsgi
from run import app_server as app  # noqa

application = tornado.wsgi.WSGIApplication([
    (r"/", app),
])
```

I am getting something, but the JavaScript parts seem to be not executed. I did add the D3.js file onto the root directory.

[image]

This is how it's supposed to look

[image]

server.log

```
2020-04-20 15:54:06 Mon Apr 20 15:54:06 2020 - received message 0 from emperor
2020-04-20 15:54:06 SIGINT/SIGQUIT received...killing workers...
2020-04-20 15:54:07 worker 1 buried after 1 seconds
2020-04-20 15:54:07 goodbye to uWSGI.
2020-04-20 15:54:07 chdir(): No such file or directory [core/uwsgi.c line 1610]
2020-04-20 15:54:07 VACUUM: unix socket /var/sockets/ABC123.pythonanywhere.com/socket removed.
2020-04-20 15:54:10 *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.17.1 (64bit) on [Mon Apr 20 15:54:08 2020] ***
2020-04-20 15:54:10 compiled with version: 5.4.0 20160609 on 09 January 2020 17:57:39
2020-04-20 15:54:10 os: Linux-4.4.0-1100-aws #111 SMP Thu Jan 9 16:34:29 UTC 2020
2020-04-20 15:54:10 nodename: blue-liveweb5
2020-04-20 15:54:10 machine: x86_64
2020-04-20 15:54:10 clock source: unix
2020-04-20 15:54:10 pcre jit disabled
2020-04-20 15:54:10 detected number of CPU cores: 2
2020-04-20 15:54:10 current working directory: (unreachable)/etc/uwsgi/vassals
2020-04-20 15:54:10 detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
2020-04-20 15:54:10 *** dumping internal routing table ***
2020-04-20 15:54:10 [rule: 0] subject: path_info regexp: \.svgz$ action: addheader:Content-Encoding:gzip
2020-04-20 15:54:10 *** end of the internal routing table ***
2020-04-20 15:54:10 chdir() to /home/ABC123/
2020-04-20 15:54:10 limiting number of processes to 60...
2020-04-20 15:54:10 your processes number limit is 60
2020-04-20 15:54:10 your memory page size is 4096 bytes
2020-04-20 15:54:10 detected max file descriptor number: 123456
2020-04-20 15:54:10 building mime-types dictionary from file /etc/mime.types...
2020-04-20 15:54:10 552 entry found
2020-04-20 15:54:10 lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
2020-04-20 15:54:10 thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
2020-04-20 15:54:10 uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /var/sockets/ABC123.pythonanywhere.com/socket fd 3
2020-04-20 15:54:10 Python version: 3.7.5 (default, Nov 14 2019, 22:26:37)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
2020-04-20 15:54:10 *** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
2020-04-20 15:54:10 Python main interpreter initialized at 0x10bd320
2020-04-20 15:54:10 your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
2020-04-20 15:54:10 your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
2020-04-20 15:54:10 setting request body buffering size to 65536 bytes
2020-04-20 15:54:10 mapped 334256 bytes (326 KB) for 1 cores
2020-04-20 15:54:10 *** Operational MODE: single process ***
2020-04-20 15:54:10 initialized 38 metrics
2020-04-20 15:54:10 WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 2 seconds on interpreter 0x10bd320 pid: 1 (default app)
2020-04-20 15:54:10 *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
2020-04-20 15:54:10 gracefully (RE)spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 1)
2020-04-20 15:54:10 spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 4, cores: 1)
2020-04-20 15:54:10 metrics collector thread started
2020-04-20 15:54:10 spawned 2 offload threads for uWSGI worker 1
2020-04-20 15:54:12 announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
```

error.log

```
2020-04-20 15:54:12,530: 200 GET / (10.0.0.121) 9.19ms
2020-04-20 15:54:19,930: 200 GET / (10.0.0.121) 4.68ms
2020-04-20 15:54:20,138: 404 GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css (10.0.0.121) 0.38ms
2020-04-20 15:54:20,147: 404 GET /static/js/jquery.min.js (10.0.0.121) 0.27ms
2020-04-20 15:54:20,148: 404 GET /static/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css (10.0.0.121) 0.26ms
2020-04-20 15:54:20,148: 404 GET /static/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css (10.0.0.121) 0.21ms
2020-04-20 15:54:20,159: 404 GET /static/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css (10.0.0.121) 0.20ms
2020-04-20 15:54:20,160: 404 GET /static/css/visualization.css (10.0.0.121) 0.28ms
2020-04-20 15:54:20,249: 404 GET /static/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js (10.0.0.121) 0.30ms
2020-04-20 15:54:20,250: 404 GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js (10.0.0.121) 0.40ms
2020-04-20 15:54:20,250: 404 GET /static/js/bootstrap-slider.min.js (10.0.0.121) 0.25ms
2020-04-20 15:54:20,251: 404 GET /static/js/d3.min.js (10.0.0.121) 0.25ms
2020-04-20 15:54:20,267: 404 GET /static/js/ChartModule.js (10.0.0.121) 0.24ms
2020-04-20 15:54:20,287: 404 GET /static/js/NetworkModule_d3.js (10.0.0.121) 0.23ms
2020-04-20 15:54:20,347: 404 GET /static/js/Chart.min.js (10.0.0.121) 0.30ms
2020-04-20 15:54:20,358: 404 GET /static/js/TextModule.js (10.0.0.121) 0.29ms
2020-04-20 15:54:20,359: 404 GET /static/js/runcontrol.js (10.0.0.121) 0.23ms
2020-04-20 15:54:20,390: 404 GET /static/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js (10.0.0.121) 0.23ms
2020-04-20 15:54:20,513: 404 GET /static/js/bootstrap-slider.min.js (10.0.0.121) 0.33ms
2020-04-20 15:54:20,628: 404 GET /static/js/d3.min.js (10.0.0.121) 0.32ms
2020-04-20 15:54:20,796: 404 GET /static/js/ChartModule.js (10.0.0.121) 0.31ms
2020-04-20 15:54:20,920: 404 GET /static/js/NetworkModule_d3.js (10.0.0.121) 0.32ms
2020-04-20 15:54:21,100: 404 GET /static/js/Chart.min.js (10.0.0.121) 0.29ms
2020-04-20 15:54:21,208: 404 GET /static/js/TextModule.js (10.0.0.121) 0.30ms
2020-04-20 15:54:21,331: 404 GET /static/js/runcontrol.js (10.0.0.121)  0.36ms
```

I feel like this is very close to being successful (I could be wrong), but I'm very new about web development. Any hint or suggestion will be appreciated.

---

Edits: Thanks to the suggestions by @Ionut_Ticus and @Filip, I have uploaded the .css and .js files and PythonAnywhere seems to recognized them. It looks a lot closer, the charts and upper panel are updated. But the sliders are missing, and when I clicked start, the graphs are not updated as it's supposed to.

[image]

server.log

```
2020-04-21 16:23:32 Tue Apr 21 16:23:32 2020 - received message 0 from emperor
2020-04-21 16:23:32 SIGINT/SIGQUIT received...killing workers...
2020-04-21 16:23:33 worker 1 buried after 1 seconds
2020-04-21 16:23:33 goodbye to uWSGI.
2020-04-21 16:23:33 chdir(): No such file or directory [core/uwsgi.c line 1610]
2020-04-21 16:23:33 VACUUM: unix socket /var/sockets/ABC132.pythonanywhere.com/socket removed.
2020-04-21 16:23:45 *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.17.1 (64bit) on [Tue Apr 21 16:23:34 2020] ***
2020-04-21 16:23:45 compiled with version: 5.4.0 20160609 on 09 January 2020 17:57:39
2020-04-21 16:23:45 os: Linux-4.4.0-1100-aws #111 SMP Thu Jan 9 16:34:29 UTC 2020
2020-04-21 16:23:45 nodename: blue-liveweb5
2020-04-21 16:23:45 machine: x86_64
2020-04-21 16:23:45 clock source: unix
2020-04-21 16:23:45 pcre jit disabled
2020-04-21 16:23:45 detected number of CPU cores: 2
2020-04-21 16:23:45 current working directory: (unreachable)/etc/uwsgi/vassals
2020-04-21 16:23:45 detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
2020-04-21 16:23:45 *** dumping internal routing table ***
2020-04-21 16:23:45 [rule: 0] subject: path_info regexp: \.svgz$ action: addheader:Content-Encoding:gzip
2020-04-21 16:23:45 [rule: 1] subject: path_info regexp: /.well-known/acme-challenge/ action: continue:
2020-04-21 16:23:45 [rule: 2] subject: path_info regexp: ^/ action: basicauth:Default Realm,admin123:agUgu8guyjhg
2020-04-21 16:23:45 *** end of the internal routing table ***
2020-04-21 16:23:45 chdir() to /home/ABC132/
2020-04-21 16:23:45 limiting number of processes to 60...
2020-04-21 16:23:45 your processes number limit is 60
2020-04-21 16:23:45 your memory page size is 4096 bytes
2020-04-21 16:23:45 detected max file descriptor number: 123456
2020-04-21 16:23:45 building mime-types dictionary from file /etc/mime.types...
2020-04-21 16:23:45 552 entry found
2020-04-21 16:23:45 lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
2020-04-21 16:23:45 thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
2020-04-21 16:23:45 uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /var/sockets/ABC132.pythonanywhere.com/socket fd 3
2020-04-21 16:23:45 Python version: 3.7.5 (default, Nov 14 2019, 22:26:37)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
2020-04-21 16:23:45 *** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
2020-04-21 16:23:45 Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1db2330
2020-04-21 16:23:45 your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
2020-04-21 16:23:45 your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
2020-04-21 16:23:45 setting request body buffering size to 65536 bytes
2020-04-21 16:23:45 mapped 334256 bytes (326 KB) for 1 cores
2020-04-21 16:23:45 *** Operational MODE: single process ***
2020-04-21 16:23:45 initialized 38 metrics
2020-04-21 16:23:45 WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 10 seconds on interpreter 0x1db2330 pid: 1 (default app)
2020-04-21 16:23:45 *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
2020-04-21 16:23:45 gracefully (RE)spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 1)
2020-04-21 16:23:45 spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 4, cores: 1)
2020-04-21 16:23:45 metrics collector thread started
2020-04-21 16:23:45 spawned 2 offload threads for uWSGI worker 1
2020-04-21 16:23:45 announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
```

error.log

```
2020-04-21 16:22:54,191: 200 GET / (10.0.0.121) 7.83ms
2020-04-21 16:23:00,511: 200 GET / (10.0.0.121) 3.87ms
2020-04-21 16:23:00,686: 304 GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css (10.0.0.121) 13.36ms
2020-04-21 16:23:00,780: 304 GET /static/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css (10.0.0.121) 2.89ms
2020-04-21 16:23:00,791: 304 GET /static/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css (10.0.0.121) 2.23ms
2020-04-21 16:23:00,807: 304 GET /static/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css (10.0.0.121) 2.23ms
2020-04-21 16:23:00,881: 304 GET /static/css/visualization.css (10.0.0.121) 2.63ms
2020-04-21 16:23:00,902: 304 GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js (10.0.0.121) 4.15ms
2020-04-21 16:23:00,906: 304 GET /static/js/jquery.min.js (10.0.0.121) 3.98ms
2020-04-21 16:23:00,983: 304 GET /static/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js (10.0.0.121) 4.12ms
2020-04-21 16:23:01,010: 304 GET /static/js/TextModule.js (10.0.0.121) 3.98ms
2020-04-21 16:23:01,015: 304 GET /static/js/bootstrap-slider.min.js (10.0.0.121) 2.93ms
2020-04-21 16:23:01,340: 304 GET /static/js/ChartModule.js (10.0.0.121) 2.33ms
2020-04-21 16:23:01,351: 304 GET /static/js/Chart.min.js (10.0.0.121) 6.25ms
2020-04-21 16:23:01,361: 304 GET /static/js/runcontrol.js (10.0.0.121) 3.54ms
2020-04-21 16:23:01,627: 404 GET /ws (10.0.0.121) 0.42ms
2020-04-21 16:23:57,914: 200 GET / (10.0.0.121) 328.06ms
2020-04-21 16:23:59,373: 404 GET /ws (10.0.0.121) 0.40ms
```

What could the `404 GET /ws` be? And why are only the sliders and text not showing?

Comment: How does the mapping of your static files look like on PythonAnywhere "Web" configuration page?

Comment: I think I have configured the static files correctly, but somehow the slider and text elements are still not showing, as well the page won't run. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume `/ws` is actually a Websocket which probably won't work with WSGI due to its asynchronous nature. If you're looking to host a Tornado app somewhere there are cloud providers that offer a free trial up to one year.

Comment: I read this page https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/UsingTornado/ and it seems to suggest Tornado server can still be hosted if you don't need to use asynchronous features, but there is no documentation or tutorial beyond this. And as a beginner, it's over my head if I should keep trying with PythonAnywhere, or switch to other hosting which plays well with asynchronous to begin with.

Comment: And could you please let me know which cloud provides they are? Thanks.

Comment: Most of these allow for 12 months of free usage [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/free/), [Vultr](https://www.vultr.com/promo/try50/), Google [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/free), Microsoft [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/); you should be able to get started with a VPS from them fairly easily.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the setup correctly, you want Tornado to serve your static files as well ; to do so you have to let it know where it can find them.
Try:

```py
application = tornado.wsgi.WSGIApplication(
    [
        (r"/", app),
    ], 
    static_path=YOUR_STATICFILES_PATH
)
```

As @Filip mentioned, it seems PythonAnywhere can serve your [static files](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/StaticFiles/) as well.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion, it advanced quite a lot but still not completely, please see my updated post.